# Javascript Regex to convert from first to second person using multiple words in a dictionary

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a Javascript function to convert a sentence from first person to second person. My current test function is as follows:

```
function statementCreator() {
    var sentence = "I went to the movies with my friend, Sally. Sally says that I'm her best friend.";

    var transforms = {
        "I" : "YOU", 
        "ME" : "YOU", 
        "MY" : "YOUR", 
        "AM" : "ARE", 
        "MINE" : "YOURS",
        "I'M" : "YOU'RE"
    };

    var pattern = `\\b(?:${Object.keys(transforms).join('|')})\\b`;
    var re = new RegExp(pattern, "g");

    str = sentence.toUpperCase().replace(re, matched => transforms[matched]);
    console.log(str);
}
```

This creates the following regex pattern:

```
/\b(?:I|ME|MY|AM|MINE|I'M)\b/g
```

Which produces the following output:

```
YOU WENT TO THE MOVIES WITH YOUR FRIEND, SALLY. SALLY SAYS THAT YOU'M HER BEST FRIEND.
```

I'm very new to Javascript and, so, this is most probably a terrible way to do this and, of course this leaves me with the word `YOU'M` as part of my output as well.

But, ideally, I'd like a solution that could:

- Allow for me to add new entries into the dictionary and they'd be added to the replacements (like was done here with the `${Object.keys(transforms).join('|')}` portion)
- Obviously, be able to deal with entries such as `I'M`.

What would be a good way to do this and, just in case anyone knows of a completely different way I could easily change from first to second person more easily / correctly, I'd **LOVE** that answer as well!!

Thanks!

Comment: Put `I` after `I'M`: `/\b(?:ME|MY|AM|MINE|I'M|I)\b/g`

Comment: Thanks, @HaoWu, that's what the one answer proposed as well. Smart and easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While whitespae bounaries will work when you are sure your words are always in between whitespace chars or start/end of string, a more universal solution in this case is simply *sorting your keys by length in descending order before creating the alternation pattern*:

```js
Object.keys(transforms).sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
```

This fixes the problem because the first alternative found stops the regex engine from trying the rest of the alternatives, please refer to the ["Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager).

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
function statementCreator() {
    var sentence = "I went to the movies with my friend, Sally. Sally says that I'm her best friend.";

    var transforms = {
        "I" : "YOU", 
        "ME" : "YOU", 
        "MY" : "YOUR", 
        "AM" : "ARE", 
        "MINE" : "YOURS",
        "I'M" : "YOU'RE"
    };

    var keys = Object.keys(transforms).sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
    var pattern = `\\b(?:${keys.join('|')})\\b`;
    var re = new RegExp(pattern, "g");

    str = sentence.toUpperCase().replace(re, matched => transforms[matched]);
    console.log(str);
}
statementCreator();
```

Output:

```
YOU WENT TO THE MOVIES WITH YOUR FRIEND, SALLY. SALLY SAYS THAT YOU'RE HER BEST FRIEND.
```

Answer (score 5):

Word boundaries won't give correct result because you have non-word characters like `'` in `I'M` and since `I` is placed before the `I'M` in alternations `\bI\b` satisfies the match in `I'm` and makes it `YOU'm`.

To address this, you may use this solution with slightly different approach in regex i.e.

```
(?<!\w)(?:I|ME|MY|AM|MINE|I'M)(?![\w'])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gEozBO/4)

- `(?<!\w)`: Negative Lookbehind to make sure we don't have a word character before the match
- `(?![\w'])`: Negative Lookahead to make sure we don't have a word character or `'` after the match

**Code:**

```js
function statementCreator() {
    var sentence = "I went to the movies with my friend, Sally. Sally says that I'm her best friend. I, the current narrator, went to the movies.";

    var transforms = {
        "I" : "YOU", 
        "ME" : "YOU", 
        "MY" : "YOUR", 
        "AM" : "ARE", 
        "MINE" : "YOURS",
        "I'M" : "YOU'RE"
    };

    var pattern = `(?<!\\w)(?:${Object.keys(transforms).join('|')})(?![\\w'])`;
    var re = new RegExp(pattern, "ig");

    str = sentence.toUpperCase().replace(re, matched => transforms[matched]);
    console.log(str);
}

statementCreator();
```

Comment: Why the negative lookaheads/lookbehinds?

Comment: I have added explanation in my answer.

Comment: I'm truly not sure which answer between yours and Wiktor's is better since this is all still very new to me, but yours seems like it would be more computationally expensive. Is it a better way to use Regex, though since it doesn't rely on ordering the options, but, rather, full matches?

Comment: Well it doesn't require any pre-processing of `keys` and gives you flexibility to keep `keys` in any order you want. Isn't that how you have in question? Also I don't see any additional performance issue with this as single character lookahead and lookbehind are quite performant in regex engine.

Comment: I ended up taking the other answer because, unfortunately, your solution breaks down if the sentence has something along the lines of `I, the current narrator, went to the movies." - which is a very possible situation. I really do like your answer, though, just not for this particular situation. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Answer has been updated to address this.

Comment: @anubhava need to remove "non-" in "we don't have a non-word character or ' after the match".

Comment: @anubhava Thank you for answer, but you did not removed "non-", only added "or - ".

Comment: @doctorgu: Sorry I edited using a mobile so could not read properly. It is fixed now.